# Moving picture box fast causes flickering C#

Tags: c#, forms, picturebox

I'm trying to move a picture box fast as it is representing a bullet. However, there is a flickering effect and it obscures the image and it is very hard to see the bullet move. I have tried to use double buffering and Invalidating the picture box before its moved but to no avail. Any suggestions? Maybe im using double buffering wrong? (I have it set to be enabled when the form is loaded.)

Code

On the Form:

```
public void Shoot(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                PictureBox bulletImage = new PictureBox();
                DoubleBuffered = true;
                StandardBullet bullet = new StandardBullet(PB_CHARA.Location.X, PB_CHARA.Location.Y, FRM_GAME.MousePosition.X, FRM_GAME.MousePosition.Y, this.ClientRectangle, bulletImage);
                Controls.Add(bulletImage);
            }
        }
```

Within the Standard Bullet class:

```
public class StandardBullet
    {
        public string ImageName = "DataBaseMod.Properties.Resources.StandardBullet_3x";
        public int sizeX = 15;
        public int sizeY = 19;
        public int x = 0;
        public int y = 0;
        int charaPostitionX;
        int charaPostitionY;
        PictureBox bulletPoint;
        public int[] vector = new int[2];
        private System.Timers.Timer bulletTimer;
        private System.Timers.Timer RemoveTimer;
        System.Drawing.Rectangle FRMBounds;
        //public delegate void UpdateControlsDelegate();
        public StandardBullet(int charaPostiX, int charaPostiY, int MousePostiX, int MousePostiY, System.Drawing.Rectangle FRMboundaries, PictureBox bulletImage)
        {
            FRMBounds = FRMboundaries;
            bulletPoint = bulletImage;
            bulletPoint.Name = ImageName;
            string filename = ImageName;
            bulletPoint.BackgroundImage = DataBaseMod.Properties.Resources.StandardBullet_3x;
            var size = new System.Drawing.Size(sizeX, sizeY);
            bulletPoint.Size = size;
            bulletPoint.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            charaPostitionX = charaPostiX;
            charaPostitionY = charaPostiY;
            x = charaPostiX;
            y = charaPostiY;
            vector[0] = charaPostiX - MousePostiX;
            vector[1] = charaPostiY - MousePostiY;
            vectorCalc();
            bulletTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10);
            RemoveTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(100);
            bulletTimer.Elapsed += TickHandler;
            bulletTimer.AutoReset = true;
            bulletTimer.Enabled = true;
            RemoveTimer.Elapsed += removeTickHandler;
            RemoveTimer.Enabled = true;
            RemoveTimer.AutoReset = true;

        }
        public void TickHandler(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            x = x + vector[0];
            y = y + vector[1];
            moveBullet();

        }
        public void removeTickHandler(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            RemoveBullet();
        }
        public void moveBullet()
        {
            bulletPoint.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { bulletPoint.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y); }));  
        }
        public void vectorCalc()
        {
            if (vector[0] >= 1)
            {
                vector[0] = -10;
            }
            else if (vector[0] <= -1)
            {
                vector[0] = 10;
            }
            if (vector[1] >= 1)
            {
                vector[1] = -10;
            }
            else if (vector[1] <= -1)
            {
                vector[1] = 10;
            }
        }
        public void RemoveBullet()
        {
            if (
                (FRMBounds.Left >= bulletPoint.Bounds.Left) || 
                ( FRMBounds.Right <= bulletPoint.Bounds.Right) || 
                (FRMBounds.Top >= bulletPoint.Bounds.Top) || 
                (FRMBounds.Bottom <= bulletPoint.Bounds.Bottom)
               )
            {
                Death();
                return;
            }

        }
        public void Death()
        {
            try
            {
                bulletTimer.Enabled = false;
                bulletPoint.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { FRM_GAME.KillBullet(bulletPoint); }));
                RemoveTimer.Enabled = false;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }

        }
    }
```

Thanks!

EDIT: I am going to remove this as i think the error may have been casued by my computer. I had two other games running whilst this one and i think this may have caused the poor rendering. Ran my code this morning and everything is fine. Sorry for this.

Comment: Please show the code that's giving you trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Using WinForms for dynamic graphics purposes is not a good idea. Instead of controls, try using Graphics and draw desired object on form (or panel or anywhere you want to).

Comment: Great answer! :)